# VBA How do you pass DATE as parameter to stored procedure

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I pass the date parameter as varchar and convert because I got errors with passing  a date parameter. I still get errors but its a conversion parameter.

```
Sub GetPositions() 'xdate As Date
Dim sSQL As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set prm = New ADODB.Parameter



Sheets("Positions").Select
Range("a2:bb999999").ClearContents
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.CommandTimeout = 300000
cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial     Catalog=GlobalR;Data Source=SWP"

    Dim d As Date
    d = "2013/12/03"

    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "Get9599Delta"
    cmd.NamedParameters = True
    Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@date", adVarChar, adParamInput, 12)
    cmd.Parameters.Append prm
    cmd.Parameters("@date").Value = "'12/3/2013'"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open cmd.Execute ''''I AM GETTING AN ERROR ON THIS LINE THAT READS
     ''''''''''' CONVERSION FAILED WHEN CONVERTING DATETIME TO CHARACTER STRING

Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

here is my stored proc

```
alter PROC Get9599Delta (@date varchar(12))
AS
DECLARE @d DATETIME
SET @d = CONVERT(DateTime, @date, 104) --convert the varchar to a date
```

Any idea why I am having this conversion issue?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.8730.2175) 64-bit and my "VBAProject" is referencing "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library". I'm running SQL Server Express (64-bit) version 11.0.3156.0 (2012).

My SQL Server database stored procedure has a date parameter with a `datetime` data type. The stored procedure does *not* contain `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Here's (an edited version of) my code:

```
Sub ExecuteStoredProcedure(date_ As Date)
    Dim connection_ As New ADODB.Connection
    connection_.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=not_my_real_database_name;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    Dim command_ As New ADODB.Command

    With command_
        .ActiveConnection = connection_
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "dbo.NotMyRealProcedureName"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Date", adDBDate, adParamInput, , date_)
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub
```

If you're having similar problems, try commenting or removing all of the code after the `connection_.Open ...` call. I definitely had problems because of the connection string passed to that call and the error info shown by VBA is so minimal that it was not immediately obvious that my problem wasn't related to the date parameter in my VBA code.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved by putting `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of my stored procedure!

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@date", adDate, adParamInput, , )
```

@ is optional
[msdn ( command.CreateParameter (Name, Type, Direction, Size, Value) )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and type of parameter adDBTimeStamp

Comment: Leaving the last to parameters blanks gives an "Expected Expression" error